# Quasiconformal maps

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

currently I am studying quasiconformal maps and the following question came up during my studies. In complex analysis one learns that
$$
\{f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C : f \text{ is conformal }\} = \{z \mapsto az+b \mid a,b \in \mathbb C\},
$$
so all the conformal maps (surjective, injective with non-vanishing derivative) maps are given by the linear map up to two constants. Now for quasiconformal maps can one built a similiar equivalence, i.e.
$$
\{f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C : f \text{ is quasiconformal} \} = \quad ?
$$
Since conformal maps $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ are already included on the right hand side by defintion but so far my gues is that there should be much more maps than simply the conformal ones. For example taking some $s<-1$ then $z \mapsto z |z|^{-s}$ is $K$-quasiconformal with $K = \max(1+s,\frac{1}{1+s})$ and would already give an example for a $K$-quasiconformal map that is not conformal. Even worse in some sense, we could now compose this with any conformal map and still stay in the LHS, so maybe the question is not 100% percent correctly poised, still is there an more or less concrete answer to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you know about qc maps besides the definition? What do you know about the Beltrami equation? What book are you reading?

Comment: I know about the measurable riemann mapping theorem and basics of the Beltrami equation. I am reading chapter four of Hubbarb's Teichmüller theory book.

Comment: Then you know enough to answer your own question, just use solvability of the Beltrami equation.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I got it now: Given any map $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that is quasiconformal, is especially $K$ quasiconformal for some $K \in [0,\infty)$ hence by Measurable Riemann Mapping theorem is a solution to the Beltrami equation for some $\mu \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb C)$ such that for every $z \in \mathbb C$ one has 
$$
\partial_{\bar{z}} f(z) = \mu(z) \partial_z f(z).
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and vice versa. You also need to normalize solutions of the BE. Also you forgot that $||\mu||<1$.

Comment: Yes that is correct thank you for the quick answer!